How to connect main app with microservice rabbitMQ to use websockets from microservice
I have main app with connected webSockets, but also, I have RabbitMQ microservice with methods where I want to send message to client by websockets. Could you assist with connection?
Here is my app.module main.ts
async function bootstrap() { const logger = new WinstonLogger();
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger,
});
const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
const port = configService.get<number>('PORT');
const origin = configService.get<string>('ORIGIN');

if (origin) {
    app.enableCors({
        allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
        origin,
        credentials: true,
    });
}

app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
        transform: true,
        transformOptions: {
            enableImplicitConversion: true,
        },
        whitelist: true,
    }),
);
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get('Reflector')));
app.use(cookieParser());

await app.listen(port).catch((error) => logger.error(error.message, error.toString()));

logger.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);

bootstrap();
}

And my microservice main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
    const logger = new WinstonLogger();
    const configService = new ConfigService();
    const urls = configService.get<string>('RMQ_URLS').split(',');
    const queue = configService.get<string>('RCOM_DEVICE_IN');
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(RcomParserModule, {
        transport: Transport.RMQ,
        options: {
            urls,
            queue,
            queueOptions: {
                durable: false,
            },
        },
        logger,
    });
    await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();

How to use method from rabbitMQ to send websocket messages
See my websocket.ts file
import {
    WebSocketGateway,
    WebSocketServer,
    OnGatewayConnection,
    SubscribeMessage,
    OnGatewayDisconnect,
    MessageBody,
    ConnectedSocket,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
import { ApiTags, ApiOperation, ApiOkResponse } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { WebsocketMessageDto, PingEventDto } from './websocket.events.dto';
import { IWebsocketGatewayMessage } from './websocket.gateway.interface';

@WebSocketGateway({ namespace: 'events' })
@ApiTags('websocket')
export class WebsocketGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server;

    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Event: alarmEvent' })
    @ApiOkResponse({
        description: 'Message sent successfully.',
        type: WebsocketMessageDto,
    })
    handleAlarmMessage(message: IWebsocketGatewayMessage) {
        this.server.emit('alarmEvent', message);
    }

    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Event: eventLogEvent' })
    @ApiOkResponse({
        description: 'Message sent successfully.',
        type: WebsocketMessageDto,
    })
    handleEventLogMessage(message: IWebsocketGatewayMessage) {
        this.server.emit('eventLogEvent', message);
    }

    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Event: ping' })
    @SubscribeMessage('ping')
    handlePing(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket, @MessageBody() data: PingEventDto) {
        console.log(`Received ping from client ${client.id}: ${data.message}`);
        client.emit('ping', {
            message: 'PONG',
        });
    }

    handleConnection(client: Socket) {
        console.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
    }

    handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
        console.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
    }
}

Please, help! Thanks.
I tried to make the microservice as another app with own port
